# Issue in implementing median cut algorithm using Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, html5-canvas

I am trying to implement a code that picks out colors from an image and then gets a pallet of certain colors from all the colors of the image. I am trying to use the Median Cut Algorithm for implementing this.

Currently, I am following the steps for the Median Cut algorithm mentioned [here](https://muthu.co/reducing-the-number-of-colors-of-an-image-using-median-cut-algorithm/):

Here's a code snippet from my POC:

```js
const getColor = () => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = displayImage.width;
  canvas.height = displayImage.height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0);
  const pixelData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
  getPallete(pixelData);
};
const getPallete = (data) => {
  // data contains image data (r,g,b,a)
  if (data.length != 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
      let [red, green, blue] = [data[i], data[i + 1], data[i + 2]];

      if (red < channelProperties.minRed) {
        channelProperties.minRed = red;
      }
      if (red > channelProperties.maxRed) {
        channelProperties.maxRed = red;
      }

      // Update minimum and maximum values for green channel
      if (green < channelProperties.minGreen) {
        channelProperties.minGreen = green;
      }
      if (green > channelProperties.maxGreen) {
        channelProperties.maxGreen = green;
      }

      // Update minimum and maximum values for blue channel
      if (blue < channelProperties.minBlue) {
        channelProperties.minBlue = blue;
      }
      if (blue > channelProperties.maxBlue) {
        channelProperties.maxBlue = blue;
      }
    }
    // gets the channel with highest range
    let highestChannel = getChannel();
    //This sorts the image data based on highest channel
    let sortedData = sortImageData(data, highestChannel);
    //This gives back the middle index
    let median = getMedian(sortedData);
    //Here I break the array from median and resend it
    const lowerPart = data.slice(0, median);
    const upperPart = data.slice(median + 1);
    getPallete(lowerPart);
    getPallete(upperPart);
  }
};
```

I have implemented the first 4 steps mentioned in the link. However, I am messing up in the last step or rather I am unable to figure out how to get my final pallet. Can anyone help in correcting this code/telling me what I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not returning anything and you don't seem to break the recursion. Also, in the linked source, it says that you have to build averages over the buckets. And you need to specify the number of colors to find, which corresponds to the number of iterations.

Here is what I think you need to add:

```
const getPallete = (data, iterations) => {
  if (data.length === 0) {
    return []
  }
  
  if(iterations <= 1){
    return [getAverageColor(data)]  // <--- build bucket average
  }

  // build upper and lower bucket, same as before
  
  return [ // <--- collect and return recursion result
    ...getPallete(lowerPart, iterations-1),
    ...getPallete(upperPart, iterations-1)
  ]
}

const getAverageColor = (data) => {
  const sums = [0,0,0,0]
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      sums[j] += data[i+j]
    }
  }
  const numberOfPixels = data.length / 4
  return sums.map(v => Math.round(v/numberOfPixels))
}
```

Here is a quick [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/median-cut-fr4nhw?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Comment: This led me to a point where I am getting NaN values for some colors. But it seems this will point me to the right path. I am trying to find the reason for NaN right now

Comment: Oh, interesting. My guess is that it's an algebraic operation with `undefined`, likely from accessing an array index that is not set. I assume `sortImageData()` does quite a bit of copying, so this seems like a place to look.

Comment: Found the issue, I was skipping the middle index when slicing the array (the ``upperPart`` line was incorrect). This was later leading to ``undefined`` as the for loop in ``getAverageColor`` function incremented by ``4``  for every iteration.

However, I am still quite far from the solution since I am getting dark color shades that are not part of the image

Comment: Oh, found an error in `getAverageColor()`, the averages have to be divided by `data.length / 4`, not `data.length`. I think this is why you got darker shades (sorry!).

Comment: No worries, your code has already helped me a lot by showing me the correct way ahead, thanks a ton! As for my progress, I refactored my code (almost) from scratch. I am 90% close from what I understand. Will check tomorrow now.